# jQuery Show/Hide not working with Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, show-hide

I am upgrading to Bootstrap 4 and noticed that all of our jQuery show/hide's are not working properly when using a hidden attribute.  If I remove the hidden attribute after the show() it works correctly.  This wasn't necessary with Bootstrap 3.

Unfortunately we have about 1400 show/hide's that I would have to change in order to upgrade to Bootstrap 4. Anyone know what the issue is, or a simple solution to fix this without changing 1400 lines of code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $("p").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function() {
    $("p").show();
    //$("p").removeAttr("hidden");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p hidden>If you click on the "Hide" button, this paragraph should disappear.</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should inclue first in the head the link tag to the bootstrap.css code and then at the en of any tag and before the closing body tag you must add ***in order*** Jquery.js popper.js (if used in your code) and then the bootstrap.js file

Comment: Thank you Med Okl!

Comment: Hi Med Okl.  I changed the order and added jQuery.js and popper.js first, but the show/hide still didn't work properly..

Answer (score 0):

Everything work fine, you need to include jquery previously, and then bootstrap.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $("#test").removeClass('d-block').addClass('d-none');
  });
  $("#show").click(function() {
    $("#test").removeClass('d-none').addClass('d-block');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p id="test" class="d-none">If you click on the "Hide" button, this paragraph should disappear.</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Vanya!

Comment: Vanya, I noticed in your code the <p> tag does not have the hidden attribute. When you add the hidden attribute it no longer works. That is the issue I'm running into where we have hundreds of elements that are hidden on startup.

Comment: Gru1, i updated my code, adding the bootstrap classes 'd-none' and 'd-block' for using visibility of elements, please check now

Comment: Thank you Vanya, your code works just as I need it to.  Unfortunately I need to change hundreds of lines of code to convert from a hidden attribute to the d-none class. My code works if you change to Bootstrap 3.4.1, but something in Bootstrap 4 breaks it.  I need to figure out what that is so that I can try to override it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because, `Bootstrap` library loads first and `jQuery` functionality not getting at the first side.

Try to change sequence like **`jQuery`** <kbd>></kbd> **`Boostrap`**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $("p").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function() {
    $("p").show();
    //$("p").removeAttr("hidden");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p hidden>If you click on the "Hide" button, this paragraph should disappear.</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

Comment: Thank you cursorrux!

Comment: Hi cursorrux. Your code snippet looks like it works, it doesn't look like is actually using Bootstrap. If you add rel="stylesheet" to the link tag it will change to the bootstrap buttons, but the show/hide no longer works.